# not all variables bound when returning inserted id Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, auto-increment

I'm trying to get the new id when inserted new data in database table, but I got:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

I'm doing it from a Java SE project,

```
 public ResultSet ejecutarConsulta(String instruccionSql){
        rs = null;
        try {
                st = con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(instruccionSql);
                System.out.println("Consulta Exitosa");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en la Consulta: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

And the String "instruccionSql" that i'm passing is

```
     insert  into Usuario(DOCUMENTOIDENTIDAD,NOMBRE,CARGO,CONTRASENA,PERMISO)
 values ('22323','asfa','Administrador','123456','0')
 RETURNING ID INTO :temp
```

I have the corresponding trigger and Seq to generate the table autoincrement id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter(int,%20int)) and register the OUT parameter.
This is an excellent opportunity to register the IN parameters too.

```
String mySql = "DECLARE x NUMBER; BEGIN "
        + "  insert  into Usuario(DOCUMENTOIDENTIDAD,NOMBRE,CARGO,CONTRASENA,PERMISO) "
        + "  values (?,?,?,?,?) "
        + "  RETURNING ID INTO x;"
        + "  ? := x;"
        + "END; ";
CallableStatement cal = conn.prepareCall(mySql);

cal.setString(1, "22323");
cal.setString(2, "asfa");
cal.setString(3, "Administrador");
cal.setString(4, "123456");
cal.setString(5, "0");
cal.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

cal.executeQuery();

Integer newId = cal.getInt(6);
```

Comment: Hi, i´m trying this your way without IN parameters with only the output so I write  cal.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER); but its saying that The IN or OUT parameter is missing from the index :: 2, but only have the '?' at,  "? := x;"

Comment: @Jomazao please paste your actual code to the question, it's very hard to diagnoze  the error without looking at source code.

Comment: I do this and works,  
    CallableStatement cal = con.prepareCall(consulta);
            cal.setString(2, "");
            cal.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            cal.executeQuery();
            Integer cosa=cal.getInt(1);
the query=DECLARE x NUMBER; BEGIN  insert  into Usuario(DOCUMENTOIDENTIDAD,NOMBRE,CARGO,CONTRASENA,PERMISO) values ('123456','asfasf','Administrador','123456','0') RETURNING ID INTO :x; 
? :=x;
END;

Answer (score 0):

you are attempting to use a bind variable (:i) that is not bound to a value.

Comment: Can you explain me, the way to do that.

Comment: may be there is some conflict when use binding variable to sql
miss match data type